# Check if object is within css border/ css wrapper

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, coordinates

I would like to begin with saying i am new to the whole programming scene. This is my first jQuery project for ICT at school.

The project:

I have multiple draggable objects (images). They are in #wrapper, wrapper is in my style.css

Now i want to make it so that when the images are dragged over a background image (**centered**), located under the wrapper, they will change from image. I have done this successfully by getting the location of each object:

```
     drag: function(){
        var who = $("#draggable1");
        var offset1 = who.offset();
        var xPos1 = offset1.left;
        var yPos1 = offset1.top;
        $('#posX').text('x: ' + xPos1);
        $('#posY').text('y: ' + yPos1);
```

Then check where the object is, and if its within the X and Y of my background picture, they change:

```
    if(yPos1 > '115' && yPos1 < '578')
            {
            this.src = 'pinkward5.png'
            }
```

And also code if the object is dropped outside of the background image, this will make it go back to its original place:

```
    if(xPos1 < '717' || xPos1 > '1202')
            {
            who.animate({ 'top': offset1.top == '0', 'left': offset1.left == '0'}, 200, function(){
            who.stop( true,true );
            who.mouseup();
            this.src = 'visionward.png'
            });
```

**BUT:**

If i use another monitor with another resolution or leave the browser on the half of my screen, the coordinates change, and the code doenst work as it should because the offset changes. 

**My question:** 

How can i make that no matter what the resolution or window of the browser, the coordinates are the same. Maybe with percentages or check if the object is within the css border of the background image?

Thanks! i hope i have not violated the stackoverflow rules.

Answer (score 0):

Why to hardcode the coordinates?
Simply call "offset()" on the background image to get the coordinates, exactly like what you did on the draggable element, and calculate the bounds with its width and height.

```
var bkgd = $('.whatever-you-name-the-background-image-class');
var bkgd_offset = bkgd.offset();
if(xPos1 >= bkgd_offset.left && xPos1 + who.width() <= bkgd_offset.left + bkgd.width() && 
   yPos1 >= bkgd_offset.top && yPos1 + who.height() <= bkgd_offset.top + bkgd.height())
    /* draggable inside background */;
else
    /* not inside background */;
```